# Parent-Child relation in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two pages and widgets. I call page2 in page1 with selector, and my widgets are opening in page2 in the same way.

The problem is, i can call page2's functions in widget. But i can't access page1's properties(they are undefined). I think page1's dying when widgets are opened. Is it normal in Angular structure? Can I provide that page1's still running?

Thank you

in page1 view:

```
<page2></page2>
```

in page2 view:

```
<widget><widget>
```

And my widget's .ts file.

```
_page2.Test2()  //it's ok
```

I can access this way. I define _page2 in widget's constructor.
But i can't define _page1. It gives 'No provider' error.

```
_page1.Test1()  // this is not possible.
```

What might this be about? And two pages have NgModule. Page2 doesn't thrown provider error, but page1 did it.

Comment: Please add the code.

Comment: I will do as soon as possible. It's a bit complicated. :)

Comment: Don't post complicated code. Reduce the code first to the absolute minimum that allows to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this I assume ?

**app.html**

```
<page1></page1>
```

**page1.html**

```
<page2></page2>
```

**page2.html**

```
<widget1></widget1>
<widget2></widget2>
```

In this case, you have several solutions. First, inject the reference of page 1 into your widgets like so

```
constructor(
  @Inject(forwardRef(() => PageOneComponent)) private page1: PageOneComponent,
) {}
```

And before anyone tells you not to do it : **yes, this is a bad practice because it creates a strong dependency**. But this answers the question.

Second option is to create view children and assign their values on the fly :

**page1 HTML & TS**

```
<page2 #p2></page2>
@ViewChild(PageTwoComponent) p2: PageTwoComponent;
```

**page2 HTML & TS**

```
<widget1 #w1></widget1>
<widget2 #w2></widget2>
@ViewChild(WidgetOneComponent) w1: WidgetTwoComponent;
@ViewChild(WidgetTwoComponent) w2: WidgetTwoComponent;
```

**Widgets TS**

```
page1: PageOneComponent;
```

Now, in your first component, you can do

```
this.p2.w1.page1 = this;
this.p2.w2.page1 = this;
```

**But this is gross and you should not do that**.

Third solution, use a service with subjects.

**service**

```
export class MyService {
  onEvent: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  propagate() { this.onEvent.next(null); }
}
```

**widgets**

```
constructor(private service: MyService) {
  // you can call
  service.propagate();
}
```

**page 1**

```
// Subscribe to the propagation
this.service.onEvent.subscribe(() => { this.myMethod(); });
```

**This should be the way to do it**.

Comment: I tried this ways before. But they didn't give results. My problem is page1's not running during this time. I think it's about my project structure.

Comment: Some of those methods being absolutely screwed up (especially the first one), I doubt you tried all of them  ... But if your page 1 isn't running, this means your application isn't running, right  ?

Comment: My app is still running. I can use widgets smoothly. But I must call function from page1. And after I can't access them, because of that they're undefined.

Comment: If your widgets are from page 2 and page 2 is from page 1, then if you don't have page 1 "running", then you would not have page 2 and headers !

Comment: I open widgets via page2,and page2 via page1. It's not problem but if I want to go back to page1, i can't access it.

Comment: Wait : when you say "go back to page 1", you mean that your components are routed ?

Comment: No,I don't use router. I open widgets on Windowbox, it's private framework's toolkit. I guess my problem is about it.